# Javascript cannot be called twice in user control

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

I have a javascript in user control:

```
public void updateStepColor()
{
       ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "changeProgressActiveStep", "alert("Hello")", true);
}
```

The above function is in the user control. When the page is load and a button is click from the web form, the web form call the user control and let the user control execute the function.

The script runs fine when the page is load, but not run when the button is click subsequently.

I tried to debug and it seems everything is fine, except the script is not triggered when the button is click (the script manager does call it).

I tried copy the same function, rename and change to 'RegisterClientScriptBlock' but not working either.

Anyone know the possible reason? Thanks!

Comment: So you are calling this function on button click?

Comment: It might be caused if you are using ASP.Net AJAX update panels.If so, let me know, there is a work around to it!!!

Comment: Yes, both page load and button click. Only when page load works. I edit the question make it clearer.Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the button is in update panel, but the user control is not

Answer (score 0):

When you are using update panel, the rendering will not happen for scriptblock to work. As a work around put following code in pageload

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(urButton);
```

Comment: I tried it refreshes the whole page, and it's not working. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I should use page instead of this:

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, GetType(), "changeProgressActiveStep", "alert("Hello")", true);
```